# Dynamodb-serverless one to many and many to many relationships

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, dynamodb-queries

I am really new to Dynamodb and NoSQL world. I am practicing AWS' `GSI` and `LSI`. I am using serverless framework. I split my handlers multiple lambda function.I want to create my data where I can see all the restaurants and what type of beers they have its' price. Also I want to query all the beers without price. I successfully create the restaurant and it's partition key is `id`. I can able to get all the restaurant data. But I stuck in beer logic. I create api endpoint for beers like this `restaurant/{id}/createBeers`, when I made post request, I got error `"message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item"` because it asked for restaurant's id. I cant find the logic where i can add the restaurant's id to create the beers and how to get all beer's without price.

The Restaurant is one to many. Beer is many to many(Same name different price based on Restaurant). This is what I want to achieve.

```
[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "restaurent 1",
        "beers": {
            "tap-beers": [{
                    "name": "beer 1",
                    "price": "2$"
                },
                {
                    "name": "beer 2",
                    "price": "2$"
                }
            ],
            "bottle-beers": [{
                    "name": "beer 3",
                    "price": "2$"
                },
                {
                    "name": "beer 4",
                    "price": "2$"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "restaurent 2",
        "beers": {
            "tap-beers": [{
                    "name": "beer 1",
                    "price": "3$"
                },
                {
                    "name": "beer 2",
                    "price": "3$"
                }
            ],
            "bottle-beers": [{
                    "name": "beer 3",
                    "price": "4$"
                },
                {
                    "name": "beer 4",
                    "price": "6$"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**This is How I want get all the beers in the table**

```
[
  {
    "beername": "beer 1"
  },
   {
    "beername": "beer 2"
  },
   {
    "beername": "beer 3"
  },
   {
    "beername": "beer 4"
  }
]
```

**This is is my restaurant create**

```
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
module.exports.createRestaurant = async event => {
  const resquestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const params = {
    TableName: "table name",
    Item: {
      id: uuid.v1(),
      name: resquestBody.name,
      beers: [] // in here I will add beers when I can create a beer my post method path 
                // is restaurant/{id}/createBeers
    }
  }

  try {
    await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(resquestBody),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }
};
```

**This is create Beer handler**

```
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
module.exports.createBeers = async event => {
  const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: "table name",
    Item: {
      beer_name: requestBody.beer_name,
      beer_type: requestBody.beer_type,
      beer_price: requestBody.beer_price
    }
  };

  try {
    await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }
};
```

**This is my `GSI` get all beers without price**

```
module.exports.getBeers = async event => {

  const params = {
    TableName: "beer",
    IndexName: "beers",
    KeyConditionExpression: "beer_name = :beer_name",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":beer_name": "beer_name"
    },
    Limit: 1
  }

  try {
    let data = await dynamoDb.query(params).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data.Items),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }

}
```

**This is my serverless yml file**

```
functions:
  createRestaurant:
    handler: handlers/createRestaurant.createRestaurant
    events:
      - http:
          path: restaurant
          method: post
          cors: true
  getRestaurants:
    handler: handlers/getRestaurants.getRestaurants
    events:
      - http:
          path: restaurant/all
          method: get
          cors: true
  createBeers:
    handler: handlers/createBeers.createBeers
    events:
      - http:
          path: restaurant/{id}/beers
          method: post
          cors: true
  getBeers:
    handler: handlers/getBeers.getBeers
    events:
      - http:
          path: beers/all
          method: get
          cors: true
resources:
  Resources:
    table:
      Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: beer_name
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: beers
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: beer_name
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: "tableName"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Entities + Relationships

From what I gather you have a two entities:

- Restaurant

  - ID
  - Name
- Beer

  - Name

Each restaurant may have multiple beers and each bear is either bottled or tap and also has a price.

### Access patterns

You want to enable these access patterns:

1. Get a list of restaurants
2. Get a list of beers per restaurant
3. Get a list of beers in all restaurants

### Table Layout

I propose a single table with a Global Secondary Index (GSI1) that looks like this:

#### Primary Table View

[image: Primary Key Perspective]

#### GSI1 Table View

[image: GSI1 Perspective]

### How to query

1. To get a list of all restaurants you do a query against `GSI1` with `PK=RESTAURANTS`

```py
import typing
import boto3
import boto3.dynamodb.conditions as conditions

def get_all_restaurants() -> typing.List[dict]:

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("table-name")

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=conditions.Key("GSI1PK").eq("RESTAURANTS"),
        IndexName="GSI1"
    )

    return response["Items"]
```

2. To get a list of all beers in a given restaurant, you do a query against the primary index with `PK=R<restaurant-id> and SK begins_with B` (You can replace `B` with `B-TP` for a list of all tap beers or `B-BB` for all bottled beers. Get rid of the SK-condition for all info about the restaurant.)

```py
import typing
import boto3
import boto3.dynamodb.conditions as conditions

def get_beers_in_restaurant(restaurant_id: str) -> typing.List[dict]:

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("table-name")

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=conditions.Key("PK").eq(f"R#{restaurant_id}") \
            & conditions.Key("SK").begins_with("B-")
    )

    return response["Items"]

def get_tap_beers_in_restaurant(restaurant_id: str) -> typing.List[dict]:

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("table-name")

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=conditions.Key("PK").eq(f"R#{restaurant_id}") \
            & conditions.Key("SK").begins_with("B-TB")
    )

    return response["Items"]

def get_bottled_beers_in_restaurant(restaurant_id: str) -> typing.List[dict]:

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("table-name")

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=conditions.Key("PK").eq(f"R#{restaurant_id}") \
            & conditions.Key("SK").begins_with("B-BB")
    )

    return response["Items"]
```

3. To get a list of all beers, do a query against `GSI1` with `PK=BEERS`. You will get duplicates, so you need to remove those client-side.

```py
import typing
import boto3
import boto3.dynamodb.conditions as conditions

def get_all_beers() -> typing.List[dict]:

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("data")

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=conditions.Key("GSI1PK").eq("BEERS"),
        IndexName="GSI1"
    )
    
    list_with_duplicates = [item["name"] for item in response["Items"]]
    list_without_duplicates = list(set(list_with_duplicates))

    return [{"beername": name} for name in list_without_duplicates]
```

### Adding items to the table

When you now add items to the table, you have to consider what type of entity you want to create.

#### Adding a Restaurant

Restaurants are pretty simple, they just need an ID and a name. From these information, we can compute the key-attributes:

```py
import boto3

def create_restaurant(restaurant_id: str, name: str) -> None:
    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("data")

    item = {
        "PK": f"R#{restaurant_id}",
        "SK": "META",
        "GSI1PK": "RESTAURANTS",
        "GSI1SK": f"R#{restaurant_id}",
        "type": "RESTAURANT",
        "id": restaurant_id,
        "name": name
    }

    table.put_item(
        Item=item
    )
```

#### Add a beer to a restaurant

The beer always belongs to a restaurant, so we need to have it's id - it also always has a price and a name.

```py
import boto3

def create_beer_for_restaurant(restaurant_id: str, name: str, price: str, is_tap: bool):

    table = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("data")

    sk = f"B-TB#{name}" if is_tap else f"B-BB#{name}"

    item = {
        "PK": f"R#{restaurant_id}",
        "SK": sk,
        "GSI1PK": "BEERS",
        "GSI1SK": f"B#{name}",
        "name": name,
        "price": price
    }

    table.put_item(
        Item=item
    )
```

Comment: Can I chat with you??

Comment: I prefer keeping it in the comments, so future readers can benefit.

Comment: aaah True story.

Comment: I am code based learner. Can you please able show me in code based How I should do that?

Comment: I don't speak node, but I've added a few Python examples. I forgot to update a few names in the sample table - for some beers the name shows the wrong number.

Comment: Daam it. I don't know Python that much.

Comment: AttributeDefinitions:
     - AttributeName: PK
         AttributeType: S
     - AttributeName: SK
         AttributeType: S
     - AttributeName: GSI1PK
           AttributeType: S
     - AttributeName: GSI1SK
            AttributeType: S
  KeySchema:
     - AttributeName: PK
          KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: SK
          KeyType: RANGE
   GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: "GSI1"
           KeySchema:
             - AttributeName: "GSI1PK"
               KeyType: "HASH"
              - AttributeName: "GSI1SK"
                KeyType: "RANGE"

Comment: I define my serverless Yml like this

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: No Sir, I am wrapping my head around How to do post and query based your suggestion

Comment: I feel like I am close but still so far: https://tenor.com/view/so-close-dog-swimming-pool-gif-15044972

Comment: I published an Intro do DynamoDB as a blog post last week and there are some links to useful re:invent talks at the end, maybe that helps: https://aws-blog.de/2021/03/dynamodb-in-15-minutes.html

Comment: How I can create post request based on sort key

Comment: const params = {
    TableName: "TableNAME",
    Item: {
      PK: `R#${uuid.v1()}`,
     SK: ???
      name: resquestBody.name
   
    }

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Added examples for creating items.

Comment: I bought Alex Debrie's book. He explain pretty much same like you. Thanks for the help.  Need to learn entities very well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229680/discussion-between-krisna-and-maurice).